# JavascriptException when adding highcharts to gwt application

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, highcharts

I am using GWT Highcharts but I am not able to render the application because it gives a Javascript Exception.

I have followed the following configuration steps for my project, say the name is GWTProject.

1. Included the jar:  org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts-1.7.0.jar
2. In the GWTProject.gwt.xml, added

   ```
   <inherits name="org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.Highcharts"/>
   ```
3. In the GWTProject.html, added the following:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
   ```
4. My code looks like this:

   ```
   import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.Chart;
   import org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.Series;
   import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
   import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

   public class GWTProject implements EntryPoint {
       public void onModuleLoad() {

           Chart chart = new  Chart().setType(Series.Type.SPLINE).setChartTitleText("Nice Chart") .setMarginRight(10);

           Series series = chart.createSeries()
           .setPoints(new Number[] { 163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628 });
           chart.addSeries(series);

           RootPanel.get().add(chart);

       }
   }
   ```

This looks correct to me but still I am getting the following exception on the line 
            RootPanel.get().add(chart);

> Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart::nativeRenderChart(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;ZZLcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)([string: 'Chart', JavaScript object(7), bool: false, bool: false, JavaScript object(28), JavaScript object(29), JavaScript object(30), JavaScript object(21), JavaScript object(24), JavaScript object(20), JavaScript object(22), JavaScript object(23), JavaScript object(25), JavaScript object(27)]): $wnd.Highcharts is undefined at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91) at org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart.nativeRenderChart(BaseChart.java) at org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart.onLoad(BaseChart.java:2497) at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:359) at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.setParent(Widget.java:484) at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.adopt(Panel.java:124) at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel.add(ComplexPanel.java:105) at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel.add(AbsolutePanel.java:97) at com.example.gwt.GWTProject.onModuleLoad(GWTproject.java:16)

Comment: In your GWTProject.html, does the script loading your GWT application (something.nocache.js) is AFTER the scripts of your point 3 ?

Comment: The issue was that I was adding jquery js but I removed it and added stand-alond framework.js and that solved my problem